# Regex match wrapped phrase with same delimiter (among many)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, domparser

I need to parse the style attribute from an html corpus (contains many different html entries with many different style attribute).

An example of HTML may be the following :

```
<span style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman';">
<span style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman";'>
```

So style attribute content is some text wrapped between single (') or double (") quotes.
If the text start to be wrapped between single quote, then should be readen until closing single quote is met. If start with a double quote, should proceede until the closing double quote is met.

I have produced the following regex, that work quite well :

```
/style\s*=\s*(?:'|").+?(?:'|")/gmi
```

The problem is that my solution fail to check consistency between opening quote and closing quote, so it will produce solution like :

```
style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman'  --missing--> ;"
style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman"  --missing--> ;'
```

Is there a solution to check both cases with one regex, or the only option is to split the current regex in two regex that will check for single or double quotes?

Comment: Have a look into [backreferences](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences) ... [`/(["']).*?\1/g`](https://regex101.com/r/DQ6gXG/1) ... but a far more reliable approach was to utilize [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [`parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my above comment ...

> *"Have a look into [backreferences](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences) ... [/(["']).*?\1/g](https://regex101.com/r/DQ6gXG/1) ..."*

```js
const markup = `
  <span style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman';">foo</span>
  <span style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman";'>bar</span>
`;
const regXStyleAttr = /style\s*=\s*(["']).*?\1/gi;

console.log(
  'regex based ... markup.match(regXStyleAttr) ...',
  markup.match(regXStyleAttr)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> *"... but a far more reliable approach was to utilize DOMParser and parseFromString"*

```js
const markup = `
  <span style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman';">foo</span>
  <span style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman";'>bar</span>
`;
console.log(
  'dom parser based ... and element node mapping ...',
  Array
    .from(
      new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString(markup, "text/html")
        .body
        .getElementsByTagName('*')
    )
    .map(elmNode => `style="${ elmNode.style.cssText }"`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** ... according to following OP's comment ...*

> *"... is it tollerant as browser will be? Is it comparable or better to regex in performance? and any use of the parse over the stirng can be done without affecting the page?"* – Skary

Answer: yes - most probably - apparently.

```js
const markup_1 = `
  <span style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman';">foo</span>
  <span style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman";'>bar</span>
`;
const markup_2 = `
  <span style=font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman'>foo</span>
  <span style=font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman">bar</span>
`;
const markup_3 = `
  <span style=font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman'>foo
  <span style=font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman">bar
`;
console.log(
  'valid markup ...',
  Array
    .from(
      new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString(markup_1, "text/html")
        .body
        .getElementsByTagName('*')
    )
    .map(elmNode => `style="${ elmNode.style.cssText }"`)
);
console.log(
  'invalid markup ...',
  Array
    .from(
      new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString(markup_2, "text/html")
        .body
        .getElementsByTagName('*')
    )
    .map(elmNode => `style="${ elmNode.style.cssText }"`)
);
console.log(
  'even more broken markup ...',
  Array
    .from(
      new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString(markup_3, "text/html")
        .body
        .getElementsByTagName('*')
    )
    .map(elmNode => `style="${ elmNode.style.cssText }"`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: really interesting, i have answer to aranuld while you write this answer, and as i said to him i was afraid of parser that is not the native browser parser, but this seems the same parser (if i have well understood the MDN). Just few question due to my ignorance about the tool : is it tollerant as browser will be? Is it comparable or better to regex in performance? and any use of the parse over the stirng can be done without affecting the page?

Comment: @Skary ... oh, I did provide everything needed already with my first comment (arnaud did just take it from there). And yes, if it comes to any kind of markup, especially human generated one, a DOM parser based approach is the only way of reliably retrieving data from it. See my last _**Edit**_ of the above answer.

Comment: Thansk and sorry for the delay. Yes your suggestion and example was a very clearly explained and good idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use previous match to do it.

https://regex101.com/

> Usually referred to as a `backreference`, this will match a repeat of
> the text matched and captured by the capture group # (number)
> specified.
>
> To reduce ambiguity one may also use \g#, or \g{#} where `#` is a
> digit. /(.)\1/

```
style\s*=\s*('|")(.+?)\1
```

Did you think about use a HTML DOM parser like this one [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, exactly what i am looking and learned something new. Rgarding to the parser, i am working client side, taking HTML from a trusted source (rest API), but have to normalize the style before incorporating HTML in the current page. So use regex to strip out forbidden styles using a white list. I am afraid to use parse, because sometimes they fail to load faulty HTML that even if faulty, will be loaded by borwser (usually more tollerant). I have also tried with JQuery but had issue. Anyway this is a bit OT here

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using back reference.

Regex:

```
style\s*=\s*(["'])(.*)\1
```

check [this](https://regex101.com/r/zCqC0I/1) result.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an idea to *not* use a Regulare Expression, but instead wrap the html into a temporary div and read the style from it. Something like:

```js
const elemStrings = `<span style="font-size:0.58em;font-family:'Times New Roman';">
<span style='font-size:0.58em;font-family:"Times New Roman";'>`;
const elems = Object.assign(document.createElement(`div`), {innerHTML: elemStrings});
const styles = [...elems.querySelectorAll(`span`)].map(elem => 
  `style="${elem.style.cssText}"`);
console.log(styles);
```